# Scroll window until element is loaded in page using selenium/javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scroll, selenium-chromedriver

I need to select a image which appears on scrolling down a page. Set of images loads on hitting bottom of page and further scrolling down loads another set of images.

I tried using scroll(), scrollBy() and Actions method but none is responding.
But using scrollIntoView() method alone scrolls the page. since the image i needed to select appears only after loading on scroll is completed, i couldn't use scrollIntoView() here . Please note scroll window im trying is inside iframe and div tag.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("scroll(0,400)");

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
```

Comment: have u tried by scroll to element position?

Comment: Element is visible only after scroll. so couldn't use scroll to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scroll to the bottom, set the `scrollTop` property to a maximum. The container having the scrollbar is usually the `<body>`:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "document.body.scrollTop = -1 >>> 1");
```

or the `<html>`:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "document.documentElement.scrollTop = -1 >>> 1");
```

or scrollable `<div style="overflow: scroll;">` :

```
WebElement div = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(...));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "arguments[0].scrollTop = -1 >>> 1", div);
```

Note that you first need to set the context on the targeted frame.

Comment: i tried both the code but didn't help. So do we need to set the container somewhere ?. I have switched to iframe and trying this code which didn't scroll for me,

Comment: Which element has the scrollbar ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to find the element which has scrollbar. Just using inspect element found scroll bar exist inside one of div tag. please let me know how to find it

Comment: The highlighted element should match the size of the scrollbar when it is inspected. Then simply set the `scrollTop` property on this element with `executeScript`.

Comment: Identified element which matched the size of scrollbar and triggered execute script as like 3rd option, but scroll not happneing.

Comment: Are you able to scroll it from the console (inspect the div and execute `$0.scrollTop = -1 >>> 1`) ?

Comment: I'm not good at java script. just inspected the element with scroll-bar and ran $0.scrollTop = -1 >>> 1 from console. It printed some int values, bu ut no scroll happening. I tried to scroll using $0.scrollTop = -1 >>> 1 in google page, which didn't happen. Let me know if i should change something in the command. what $0 refers to ?

Comment: Only scrollIntoView() works in that page. Other methods are not working there, like scrollTop(), windowscrollBy() etc, which is required for me.

Comment: The `$0` represent is the selected element in the Element tab when the the page is inspected. For example, inspect this page, select `<body>` at the root and execute `$0.scrollTop = -1 >>> 1` in the console. You'll see that the page scrolls to the bottom. So if it doesn't work with your page, then you don't have the element holding the scrollbar.

Comment: Execute the following code in the console once you've inspected the textarea. It will list the containers with a vertical scrollbar: `[].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('html,body,div'), e => e.scrollHeight > e.offsetHeight && (e.offsetWidth - e.clientWidth) > 10)`

Comment: Yes. Scroll works fine in console and as well via code ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "arguments[0].scrollTop = -1 >>> 1", element);. There was issue in loading the contents. So handling it worked for me. Thanks :)